# .htaccess to cache SVGs with query strings

Tags: .htaccess, caching, svg

I've got a site that uses a lot of SVGs as background images. Many of the SVG files have query strings attached to them, which are used to dynamically change colors (via a bit of PHP). For example, my CSS might call an SVG like this:

```
background-image: url("/images/sprite.svg?color=00ffff");
```

I've now realised that these SVGs with query stings don't get cached which makes page loads very slow and clunky!

I tried adding this to my .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(svg)">
    ExpiresActive on 
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

But that doesn't seem to do it – looking at the Network tab of Chrome Dev Tools shows that they still have a size, rather than being "from cache".

Is it actually possible to tell a browser to cache SVGs with query strings? Is my htaccess rule wrong? Or is there another reason that Chrome wouldn't be caching them?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `ExpiresByType` directive instead. See [mod_expire](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresbytype):

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType image/svg "access plus 1 month"
```

Comment: Thanks arainone. I actually just realised that I'd made a mistake in the original post: the images actually aren't called sprite.svg?color=00ffff, they're called sprite.php?color=00ffff – so definitely weren't getting cached as they were PHP files. So I just changed the first line of my code above to "<FilesMatch "sprites\.php">" and that works. Sorry – that was a silly mistake!

Comment: @FrankHarrison Maybe update Your question and post Your comment as an answer ?